# Product flavor wise module implementation

Tags: android, build.gradle, koin, android-multi-module

I have 2 local modules, say `cat` and `dog`. Both have their platform specific code. Corresponding to these, there are two product flavors as well, say `catFlav` and `dogFlav`. The `app` module's **build.gradle** file looks something like this:

```
productFlavors {
    catFlav {
        applicationIdSuffix ".cat"
    }
    dogFlav {
        applicationIdSuffix ".dog"
    }
}

dependencies {
    catImplementation project(":platform:cat")
    dogImplementation project(":platform:dog")
    ...
}
```

In my `app` module, I have an interface called PlatformUtils. How can I have two files `CatPlatformUtilsImpl` and `DogPlatformUtilsImpl` in the respective modules, so that only the relevant file according to the flavor is picked? I'm using Koin for DI.

I've tried using the regular `implementation` instead of the flavor specific. It works fine, but I don't want to include modules from one flavor in another.